Can the trace be computed in any Schauder basis?
Edit: This question didn't get any answers after a bounty, so I cross-posted it here on Math Overflow.

Let $H$ be a separable Hilbert space and $T \in L(H)$ a trace-class operator. It is well known that the trace of $T$ is given by $\operatorname{tr}(T) = \sum_n \langle Te_n, e_n\rangle$, where $\{e_n\}_{n\in \mathbb N}$ is an orthonormal Hilbert basis. The quantity is independent of the chosen orthonormal basis and even independent of the order of summation.
In finite dimensions, however, we can represent $T$ as a matrix using any basis, not necessarily orthonormal, and summing the diagonal yields the trace. Thus, one might expect a similar result to hold for arbitrary trace-class operators.
Suppose $\{f_n\}_{n \in \mathbb N}$ is an ordered Schauder basis for $H$, and let $\pi_n$ denote the projection onto the $n\text{th}$ basis element. If $T$ is trace class, do we have $\operatorname{tr}(T) = \sum_n \pi_n(Tf_n)$? If so, is the sum always independent of order? If the suggested formula fails in general, what if we restrict to unconditional or symmetric Schauder bases?

You probably have to assume that the Schauder basis is uniformly bounded ($\sup_n|f_n|<\infty$), else the basis transformation $S:e_n\mapsto f_n$ is unbounded which might complicate things. In case of uniform boundedness, however, I expect your statement to be true because then $S$ is bounded and should be bijective (hence bounded inverse) so ${\rm tr}(STS^{-1})={\rm tr}(S^{-1}ST)={\rm tr}(T)$ which is how the finite-dimensional proof goes, as well.
